# An error occur when using a thread variadic template constractor

Tags: multithreading, c++11, variadic-templates

```
void f(vector<int>& v){
    for(const auto& x:v) cout << x;
}

class F{
private:
    vector<int> v;
public:
    F(vector<int>& vc):v{vc}{}
    void operator()(){
        for(const auto& x:v) cout << x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> some_vec{3,5,77,32,1};
    vector<int> vec{66,8,90,45,777};
    thread t1{f,some_vec};
    thread t2{F(vec)};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cout << '\n';
}
```

An error "no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of< void (*(std::vector))(std::vector&)>' occur

If the argument vector in `f` is declared as `const`, `void f(const vector<int>& v)`, the error disappears.

On the other hand, the code with function object `F` works just fine.

Code from Bjarne Stroustrup -- the C++ programming language 5.3.2 Passing Arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread` stores copies of the arguments passed to its constructor, and then uses rvalues of those copies as the arguments for a handler. That is, function `f` cannot be called with an rvalue of `std::vector`, as it expects a non-const lvalue reference. Even if you change it to a const lvalue reference, then it's a copy of what is actually passed to the `t1`'s constructor.

On the contrary, class `F` has an implicitly defined copy-constructor, and its function call operator expects no arguments, hence you get no errors. (And `F` itself is constructed before it's passed to a thread's constructor).

If you want function `f` to operate on the `some_vec` instance, you'd have to wrap it with a reference wrapper:

```
#include <functional>

std::thread t1{f, std::ref(some_vec)};
//                ~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: I am still a bit confused here. Why a copy of a const lvalue reference is  passed to the `t1`'s constructor, but not the non-const lvalue reference? The latter can also be copied, right?

Comment: @MiloLu you can think of it as if a thread makes copies of the arguments, and then move-initializes parameters of a handler. once a vector is *moved*-from (turned into an xvalue), it cannot be bound by a non-const lvalue reference. so the value category passed to the handler is `vector<int>&&`